# keyboard bounce in windows 7 professional 64 bit on a brand new lenovo e520

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I'm a heavy user of Word 2010 and just purchased a new Lenovo ThinkPad Edge e520 running Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

From the first day I've had the laptop the keyboard keeps bouncing: letters are repeated randomly without me having hit them more than once. I tried setting filter keys; when I use "repeat keys and slow keys" or even "ignore all repeated strokes" nothing seems to change. When I turn on "bounce keys" the repetition stops but then I can't type double-letter words, can't use the arrow keys, and can't use the enter key more than once without having to wait half a second between strokes (the minimum setting for bounce keys).

I have installed the latest BIOS and checked that all drivers are updated.

Is there any solution for this frustrating problem?

Answer (score 0):

Lodge a warrenty claim for a faulty keyboard.  It's not guaranteed to fix it, but is probably the best bet.

I hate to say, I have a Dell XPS 1640 that's had this issue since about a month after receiving it.  I lodged warrenty claims and replacement keyboards did not fix the issue.  I suspect there's an issue with the physical frame possibly warping the keyboard, or it could simply be how I type on a laptop keyboard (I much prefer desktop keyboards.)  I've dealt with it for two-and-a-half years now.

Comment: i actually suspect it's a software problem - i've seen several references to this type of problem with win 7 on many types of machines - but no repair.

Comment: My problem is definitely hardware.  I can type on a USB keyboard without issue.  The laptop keyboard only bounces on certain keys, most notably those surrounding 'c'.  Keys surrounding 'o' used to have a habit of missing keystrokes instead.  Also, I've used this laptop with both Windows Vista 32-bit and Windows 7 32-bit.  I have never had this problem on other computers in Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issues with my new e520, http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19328066.aspx?PageIndex=4 solves it perfectly

Comment: Welcome to Super User! [It would be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link only for future reference.